# WAR deployment to Tomcat

Tags: tomcat, spring-boot

I'm trying to deploy a Spring Boot application (Java 1.7) to a Tomcat server.
As I upload my application WAR, I receive the following error (that I don't have on my local project) :

```
No Spring WebApplicationInitializer types detected on classpath
```

Any insight on this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [No Spring WebApplicationInitializer types detected on classpath](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16321819/no-spring-webapplicationinitializer-types-detected-on-classpath)

Comment: I don't have any WEB-INF directory, so unfortunately I couldn't solve my problem thanks to this post...