# No Spring WebApplicationInitializer types detected on classpath printed while deploying from container

Tags: spring, docker, tomcat, servlets, model-view-controller

I'am trying to deploy my tomcat-app to remote server.
App deployed from docker-container (image: tomcat:9.0-jdk11).

Project-properties:

```
    <java.version>11</java.version>
    <spring.version>5.2.1.RELEASE</spring.version>
    <tomcat.version>9.0.27</tomcat.version>

    <logback.version>1.2.3</logback.version>
    <slf4j.version>1.7.28</slf4j.version>
```

But I can't run it on remote-server. At local-host it works fine.

In tomcat-logs (localhost.log) I see only one problem:

```
  org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log No Spring WebApplicationInitializer types detected on classpath
```

Other logs dont containt any issues.

I don't know is this a reason of my problems with app-running, but I want to handle it.

Notes:

1. It is not a Spring-Boot.
2. answer in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16321819/no-spring-webapplicationinitializer-types-detected-on-classpath) didn't help me...

Comment: Its an informative message not necessarily a problem. Do you have a `WebApplicationInitializer` in your applicaiton? Also if you deploy a docker container it should work equallly well locally as remote.

Comment: Yes. I find it in spring-web external library

Comment: That wasn't my question. Do you have an implementatin of that interface. I don't doubt that that interface is on your classpath. But as stated it is just an informational message NOT an error.

Comment: I dont have any implementaions of WebApplicationInitializer

Comment: Thus as stated it is only an info message. Your problem lies elsewhere